# Call an activity to make a photo calls onCreate() twice on Android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0

In Android 10, and only in Android 10, call an Activity to take a photo creates a new MainActivity.

```
private fun takePicture() {
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    val file: File = createFile()
    val uri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        this,
        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
        file
    )
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
    startActivityForResult(intent, Activities.STEPVERIFICATION_IMG_ACTIVITY)
}
```

In Android 10 onActivityResult is called after onCreate() It does not happen in any other Android version.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
```

Android 9
1 - startActivityForResult
2 - onActivityResult

Android 10
1 - startActivityForResult
2 - onCreate()
3 - onActivityResult

What might be different in Android 10?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: what is your activity config in manifest and also how you control activity lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

> In Android 10 onActivityResult is called after onCreate() It does not happen in any other Android version

This has nothing to do with Android version.

Your process is being terminated while your app is in the background. This is perfectly normal and has been a standard part of Android since Android 1.0.

What determines whether your process will be terminated depends on a lot of things, including:

- The amount of memory being used by the foreground app, and camera apps can vary widely in their memory consumption
- What other processes are running and their relative importance
- The amount of system RAM on the device

If your process is terminated, when control returns to your app, Android will fork a fresh process for you and call `onCreate()` on your new foreground activity, before it calls `onActivityResult()` to deliver you the result from the camera app.